# UserFrosting, Composer & wrong path in includeJSTop

Tags: php, composer-php, userfrosting

I recently started learning **UserFrosting**...

I managed to successfully install **highlightjs** from Packagist using Composer. All went well, new folder and all required files are created in */userfrosting/vendor/components/highlightjs*

However, **initialize.php** and it's **includeJSTop()** does inject the reference in a path pointing to */public_html/js* while files are in */userfrosting/vendor/components/highlightjs*

There is a simple solution - to copy *highlightjs.js* from */userfrosting/vendor/components/highlightjs* to */public_html/js* but I would like to know if my approach is correct. Or perhaps there is a better way where  files are copied to */public_html/js* as a part of Composer's install/update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer is for **PHP** packages.  highlight.js is a *Javascript* package, so it doesn't really make sense to load it using Composer.

There are package managers for Javascript - [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) being the most popular - but UserFrosting 0.3.1 doesn't use those out of the box (UF4 will have integrations for NPM, but that hasn't been released as of the time of this post).

Your best bet for now would indeed be to simply do a "manual install" and copy the `highlight.js` file to your `public/js` directory.  In that case, you don't need to load it with Composer.